# Menu icons toolbar on Android 5.0 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I can't load the menu items in the toolbar. I'm using the Drawer Navigation, and I can't even show the hamburger icon.

I'm using getSuportActionBar, my activity extends from ActionBarActivity, I added the toolbar xml into my activity xml.

**SOLUTION**

I found my solution here, I just added a LinearLayout as a parent in the toolbar

Appcompat Toolbar Not Showing With Navigation Drawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution here, I just added a LinearLayout as a parent in the toolbar

[Appcompat Toolbar Not Showing With Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569395/appcompat-toolbar-not-showing-with-navigation-drawer)

Answer (score 1):

You can set your favorite icon and add a listener.

```
    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }
    });
```