# Why does Toolbar in AppCompat not show when using as an ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

Google mentioned in their Android blog that there are two possibilities if one wants to use the new `Toolbar` using `AppCompat`. One is by using it as an `ActionBar` and one using it standalone, but as I am using `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, I need the first option. So I have to extend `ActionBarActivity` and my theme must inherit `Theme.Appcompat` (or one of it's variations). Also, to use the first option I had to inherit the `NoActionBar` variation. And finally, I had to call `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)`, which I did. However, the ActionBar still does not show. Below is my code.

I have already seen [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569395/appcompat-toolbar-not-showing-with-navigation-drawer), but I guess in my case it's `SwipeRefreshLayout` that ruins it. I tried different places to include the toolbar, but none of them works. How can I include the toolbar without ruining the rest of the layout? Thanks.

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders_list);

    context = getApplicationContext();


    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refreshable_content);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh_one,
            R.color.refresh_four, 
            R.color.sun_flower, 
            R.color.carrot);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_activity_orders_list);

    drawerToggleLeft = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) 
        {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_activity_orders_list);
            findViewById(R.id.action_add_order).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) 
        {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
            findViewById(R.id.action_add_order).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }



    };



    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggleLeft);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    drawerToggleLeft.syncState();


    ordersList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
}
```

**theme.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources >

    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/turquoise</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green_sea</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>


    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**custom_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/turquoise" />
```

**activity_order_list.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" /> // here is the toolbar

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".OrdersListActivity"
        android:background="@color/white" 
        android:id="@+id/refreshable_content">



        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@null"> 
        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" /> // here is the toolbar

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/drawer_fragment_left"
            android:name="com.ordr.view.DrawerFragmentLeft"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

      </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: The DrawerLayout works with 2 children.
In your case there are 3 children

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti ok, thanks! But do you have any idea what a way is to fix this? Because if I put the toolbar in the linearlayout then my toolbar shows up in the drawer and when I put it inside swyperefreshlayout it takes up the whole screen..

Comment: Actually it works with more than 2. The 1st child view is always the container view. All next children are considered nav. drawers positioned depending on their gravity. E.g. you can have double drawers on both sides. Maybe it works even with top bottom, but who knows. :)