# Android Material Design Navigation Drawer for Lower Api

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, material-design

Is it possible to make a Navigation Drawer in Material Design like the Gmail app on lower API?
If it's possible have anyone a Tutorial or a guide to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: off-topic, too broad and also unclear what you're asking, all, at the same time, in one question ... gratz

Comment: sorry but Ranjith understood it :) and for you I want to create a Navigation Drawer in Matreial Design which work on lower android versions like Android 4.0 or 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Appcompat library for it, here's a link how to set it up: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

You need to use the Toolbar to show the arrowToggle:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And in your mainView you need to add this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.guidelib_activity_main);
mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Also refer this question: [Appcompat Toolbar Not Showing With Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569395/appcompat-toolbar-not-showing-with-navigation-drawer)